# Subtracting by Dictionary Values from Iterated Total in For Loop Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration, subtraction

Working in Python 2.7.

I have a dictionary with team names as the keys and the values are contained in lists. The first value is the amount of runs the team scored, the second is runs allowed:

```
NL = {'Phillies': [662, 476], 'Braves': [610, 550], 'Mets': [656, 687]}
```

I have a function that iterates over each key and provides the total runs scored and allowed for the dictionary as a whole. I would also like to be able to subtract each individual team from the total, and create a league minus team value.

I first tried something along the lines of this:

```
def Tlog5(league, league_code):
    total_runs_scored = 0
    total_runs_allowed = 0
    for team, scores in league.iteritems():
        total_runs_scored += float(scores[0])
        total_runs_allowed += float(scores[1])
        team_removed_runs = total_runs_scored - scores[0]
```

Unfortunately, that appeared to be subtracting from only the values that had already been iterated instead of the complete total. So, for the first team in the dictionary, team_removed_runs was 0, for the second team it was the the total runs for of the first two teams minus the second teams total (leaving only the first teams total.

I tried to move the team_removed_runs = total_runs_scored - scores[0] out of the for loop, but then I only got a value for the last team in the dictionary.

Is there a way I can return the team_removed runs for all the teams in the dictionary?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the `team_removed_runs` for every team in the dictionary, you'll need to go back through the dictionary and compute the total number of runs minus the runs for each team.  Something like

```
team_removed_runs = {}
for team, scores in league.iteritems():
    team_removed_runs[team] = [total_runs_scored - scores[0],
                               total_runs_allowed - scores[1]]
```

This will use the final values of `total_runs_scored` and `total_runs_allowed` for the entire league, and then subtract each teams values from that total, storing the result in the dictionary `team_removed_runs`.  So if you wanted the value for the league total less the Phillies, you could find this at

```
team_removed_runs['Phillies']
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. Because total_runs_scored hasn't been stored yet, for the first team the function returns 0, because it's subtracting the first teams total from the total_runs_scored, which at that point only contains the first teams total. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Add the code I wrote after the code you wrote, so you have two for loops. See [pastebin of full code](http://pastebin.com/m3byYxe0).